# Using virtual audio device as Microsoft Teams (app, not web) microphone

Tags: audio, monterey, video-conference, ms-teams

This is kind-of a "Hail Mary" question, as it's obscure and weird, but I figure it can't hurt to ask.

MacOS 12.6 on an M1 Pro. I've got the MacOS version of Microsoft Teams installed, and I use a Cam Link 4K to route video from a camera for use as video for things like Teams, Zoom, Google meetings, etc. The camera works fine, but because what that Cam Link divice does is convert the HDMI stream to a USB webcam stream, it lags by 6 or 7 frames. My microphone is an ordinary USB microphone, and it also works fine.

The problem is that the video frame lag makes the audio be a little ahead (about 170 to 180 milliseconds, depending), and that freaks some people out in meetings. So I installed products from Rogue Amoeba, "Loopback" and "AudioHijack". Loopback allows creation of virtual audio devices, each with an input and an output. AudioHijack allows filters of various kinds to be added into the audio stream. Thus, AudioHijack can listen to the real microphone, route that through a 170ms delay "device", and then send the output of that to the virtual audio device.

That all works too: the delay clearly happens, and it makes Zoom through the native app work perfectly. QuickTime also uses the virtual device, and recorded video also comes out in sync. The problem is with Teams.

The Teams app allows me to choose the virtual device, and the sound works, but the delay is missing. It's as if Teams shows me the chosen device, and shows it as chosen and a (bad) volume meter definitely responds, but it decides to use the actual device anyway. I don't understand how that can be possible, but we're talking about Teams here.

So, has anybody else seen this? I've contacted the Rogue Amoeba people and tried a couple of suggestions, but they had no effect. (I'm going to get back to them; they're very nice support people.) Any suggestions (other than "delete Teams", much as I'd like to) are very welcome.

Comment: The Rogue Amoeba team are good, but it might be worth giving the MS guys a shout too. idk for Teams, but the MS RDP devs were very responsive to bug reports, often replying directly. I found this - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-early-access-to-new-teams-features-a6e387fe-1cad-4f90-ad78-1a311c77b36d - but idk if it applies to the Mac version. Once you'e in their beta channel, it should add a reporting structure to the app.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks! I will try that. (However, it's not obvious where/how to submit a bug report for Teams.)

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Teams, but when I worked with the RDP beta, there was a reporting app that would pop up. I see on the release, there's a link in the Help menu, which redirects to a web page.

Comment: @Tetsujin I really appreciate your help in any case!